# What is ubuntu doing on bootup during black screen?

Tags: boot

I have noticed that when I start up my laptop, it shows GRUB like usual but then it black screens for about 5 seconds, displays a message about support for core revisions 0X15 and 0X17 being disabled, and *then* displays the startup splash screen. What is Ubuntu doing during that black screen?

Comment: starting kernel mode setting. https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting

Answer (score 0):

Create a file `/etc/modprobe.d/local-b43.conf` containing the line

`options b43 allhwsupport=1`

Then, run the following commands

`sudo rmmod b43`

`sudo modprobe b43`

I think you are using a Broadcom (BCMxxxx) wireless card. The message is telling you to pass an option to the b43 kernel module to activate support for your wireless driver.

Comment: Hm, that's weird, my internal wireless card is working. I will try that.